# How can I use the F() object to do this with the Django ORM?

Tags: django, datetime, orm

I encountered a model like this:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    timespan = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class Todo(models.Model):
    limitdate = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task)
```

I need to extract all `Todos` with a `limitdate` that is lower or equal to today's date + a timespan defined in the related `Task` model.

Something like (dummy example):

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()
Todo.objects.filter(limitdate__lte=today + F('task__timespan'))
```

Now, I can do that with a loop but I'm looking for a way to do it with `F()`, and I can't find one.

I'm starting to wonder if I can do that with `F()`. Maybe I should use `extra` ?

Please note that I don't have the luxury of changing the model code.

Comment: Untested, but if task__timespan would be a timedelta it should work, can't you add a function to the Task model that returns self.timespan as a timedelta?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Django doesn't let you filter on method returns ;-) Even with a custom field, I don't see how it could translate this to SQL.

Comment: Ofcourse you're right, tbh I don't think it's possible with F without hacking it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there's no TIMESPAN type on a database. So, `F` cannot return something that you can actually work with in this context. I'm not sure what type of field you actually used in your database, but the only way I can think of to do this is to the store the timespan as an integer consisting of seconds, add that to "today" as a timestamp, and then convert it back into a datetime which you can use to compare with `limitdate`. However, I'm unsure if Django will accept such complex logic with `F`.

Comment: I'm going to choose this, by doing a cusmtom IntegerField that will accept dates and store timestamps.

Answer (score 6):

The main issue is that DB does not support `date + integer` and its hard to write ORM query to `date + integer::interval`, for PostgreSQL for example, where `integer` is the value of the `task_timespan` column, in days count.

However, as
`limitdate <= today + task__timespan` equals to
`limitdate - today <=  task__timespan`

We could transform the query to

`Todo.objects.filter(task__timespan__gte=F('limitdate') - today).distinct()`

thus the SQL becomes something like `integer >= date - date`, that should work in PostgreSQL because `date - date` outputs `interval` which could be compared w/ `integer` days count.

In other DBs such as SqLite, it's complicated because dates need to be cast w/ `julianday()` at first...and I think you need to play w/ `extra()` or even `raw()` to get the correct SQL.

Also, as Chris Pratt suggests, if you could use timestamp in all relative fields, the query task might become easier because of less limited add and subtract operations.

P.S. I don't have env to verify it now, you could try it first.

Comment: it is amazing! `F('limitdate') - today` works in PostgreSQL! just tested a similar case. thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, any reason why this shouldn't be working on Django 1.11? I'm getting `No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.` and I have the same field types as OP in the operation.