# Comparing two fields django filter

Tags: python, django, filter, compare

How can I compare two fields on a django query?

Basically what I want is to split in two querys the tasks delayed and on_time.

A task is delayed when the difference between today and the request date has exceded the tolerance days.

Right now I have this:

```
def dayssince(value):
    if value is None:
        return '0'
    #"Returns number of days between today and value."
    today = datetime.date.today()
    diff  = today - value
    if diff.days > 1:
        return '%s' % diff.days
    elif diff.days == 1:
        return '1'
    elif diff.days == 0:
        return '0'
    else:
        # Date is in the future; return formatted date.
        return value.strftime("%B %d, %Y")


on_time = process.(Department__Tolerance__gte=dayssince(F('Request_date'))).annotate(Counter=Count('Client'))
delayed = process.(Department__Tolerance__lte=dayssince(F('Request_date'))).annotate(Counter=Count('Client'))
```

But I'm getting attribute error:
       **'ExpressionNode' object has no attribute 'days'**

Answer (score 0):

F expressions do not return values to be used in Python, so your function is being called on an SQL expression, hence the error. They are used to encapsulate *database* operations. Python never sees the field value.

You can use a number of other operations in F expressions: [Supported Operations with F](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#supported-operations-with-f). In particular, you can use the Python timedelta object to compare dates; see [F expressions in Filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters).

Comment: I'm having the same problem with your solution:  

"unsupported type for timedelta days component: F", timedelta doesn't seem to support the F object.

Comment: The F expression would look something like: `Department__Tolerance__gt=F('request_date') - datetime.date.today()`

Comment: Seems to work , however I´m still getting a date as a result, is there any way I can convert it to an integer in order to compare it with the field "Tolerance"(int)?

Comment: If it's a date and not a timedelta obj, I'm skeptical this can actually be done (my bad). [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457119/how-can-i-use-the-f-object-to-do-this-with-the-django-orm) suggests the same; you'd need to store datetimes using integers.